# how control if required message visible then not visible email invalid message?Angular js

Tags: angularjs

In my program, I written email validation code when submit button is clicked, it will call validation function , there I am providing message text to view.here problem is when clicked on button both message(required and invalid) showing. But I want show first need to check required field after that email format validation. how can show first required field message.if required field entered I need to hide required filed message, I need to show Invalid message. I tried bellow code.

**html**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController" novalidate>
<form name="login">
        <p>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <span> <input type="text" value="" ng-model="reg.email" size="40" id="email"
                        name="reg_email"  ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/"/>
                    </span>
                    <span ng-show="login.reg_email.$error.required"><p ng-show="errorMsgShow" class="red">{{requiredMsg}}</p></span>
                    <span ng-show="login.reg_email.$invalid"><p ng-show="errorMsgShow" class="red">{{invalidEmailMsg}}</p></span>
                </p>
        <button ng-click="validation()" >submit</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

**script**

```
function LoginController($scope) {
    $scope.validation = function(){
      $scope.requiredMsg="This question is required";
            $scope.invalidEmailMsg = "invalid Email";
            $scope.errorMsgShow = true;
        }
}
```

**css**

```
.red{
  color:#f20;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4377/)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited you code and this works fine:

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController" novalidate>
<form name="login">

                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <span> <input type="text" ng-model="email" size="40" id="email"
                        name="reg_email"  ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/"/>
                    </span>
                    <span class="red" ng-show="login.reg_email.$dirty && login.reg_email.$error.required">This field is required</span>
                    <span class="red" ng-show="login.reg_email.$invalid && login.reg_email.$dirty">Invalid input</span>

        <button ng-click="validation()" >submit</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function LoginController($scope) {


    $scope.validation = function(){
        console.log($scope.login.reg_email.$dirty)
            console.log($scope.login.reg_email.$error.required)
        }
}
```

Comment: i tried, both message showing at time, please help me

Comment: your jsfiddle also not working, when clicked on button both message showing at time

Comment: use the code i have written above, not the jsfiddle.

Comment: i updated your code into jsfiddle , but still it is not working ? https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/4380/

Comment: when i clicked button not showing only while typing it showing@Nitesh

Comment: So what do you want exactly.?

Answer (score 0):

Use '$error.pattern' instead of '$invalid' and use 'Div' instead of 'span' to display error messages.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController" novalidate>
  <form name="login">
    <p>
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <span> <input type="text" ng-model="reg.email" size="40" id="email"
                        name="reg_email" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/"/>
                    </span>
      <div ng-show="login.reg_email.$error.required">
        <p ng-show="errorMsgShow" class="red">{{requiredMsg}}</p>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="login.reg_email.$error.pattern">
        <p ng-show="errorMsgShow" class="red">{{invalidEmailMsg}}</p>
      </div>
    </p>
    <button ng-click="validation()">submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the conditions, as well as tag, please try this way. It sould work for you

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController" novalidate>
<form name="login">
        <p>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <span> <input type="text" value="" ng-model="reg.email" size="40" id="email"
                        name="reg_email"  ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/"/>
                    </span>
                    <div ng-show="login.reg_email.$error.required && (login.reg_email.$invalid)"><p class="red">{{requiredMsg}}</p></div>
                    <div ng-show="login.reg_email.$invalid && (!login.reg_email.$error.required)"><p ng-show="errorMsgShow" class="red">{{invalidEmailMsg}}</p></div>
                </p>
        <button ng-click="validation()" >submit</button>
        </form>
</div>
```